# A questions on positive measure on compact topological groups

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, topological-groups

If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two positive measures on a compact topological group $G$ such that $0\leq \nu\leq \mu$. Assume $h$ is a probability measure such that $\mu*h=h*\mu=\mu(G)h$, then $\nu*h=h*\nu=\nu(G)h$.

Where $*$ is convolution of measures. Such an lemma is used in proof of Haar state on any compact Quantm gorup. I just want to see how we can prove this in case of $C(G)$.

Comment: Why aren't you satisfied with the proof for compact quantum groups?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I am satisfied with that proof. But I was thinking in C(G), there should be simpler proof. The proof in compact quantum groups uses a lot of machinery to prove it. The comment about compact Quantum group was from where this question came.

Comment: I think the proof for quantum groups does not use much machinery: isn't this a simple compactness argument together with some tensor calculus? What proof did you read about the existence of the Haar measure?

Comment: We don't need compactness argument for this lemma. (that is to prove the existence of Haar state). Yes it is some tensor calculus which I want to avoid while proving the above lemma mentioned in the question because when we talk of measures on $C(G)$ and want to prove something for it, tensor calculus does not naturally come